# Pulling the userDetails in custom LogoutHandler Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

In MyLogoutHandler class I do override determineTargetUrl() method, here I am calling `MyUserDetials userDetails = (MyUserDetials)userContextManager.getUserDetails()`, but userDetails is null.

here is the configuration:

```
<security:logout  
invalidate-session="true"
success-handler-ref="MyLogoutHandler"
logout-url="/auth/logout"/>
```

I noticed that since invalidate-session="true", it is null? but I like to keep this attribute "true", Can I have any other way to do configure?

My goal is: I need to pull some information from userDetails, to make a webservice call after user clicks logout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I created the My Own Handler and did override the:

```
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {...}
```

method of `*SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler*`. Now I am able to get `*authentication*` object according to my spring configuration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need create your own [LogoutHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html), implement

```
 void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication);
```

add it implementation to `security:logout` tag. After get user details from `authentication` parameter.

Comment: I did try this method, according to my spring configuration, this does't work, though it helps me to think. Thank you.